# Listmover events only trigger once in the run time

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have two listboxes input and output and I want to move item from one to another. So I made a class(`CListMover`) with these variables:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_blnRemoveOnMove As Boolean
Private m_DeleteItemFromList As Boolean
Private m_ReverseListBox As Boolean

Public WithEvents MoveUpButton As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents MoveDownButton As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents TransferButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Public UpDownList As MSForms.ListBox

Public transferFromList As MSForms.ListBox
Public WithEvents TransferToList As MSForms.ListBox

Public OutputText As MSForms.TextBox


Private Sub TransferButton_Click()
     msgbox "Only fires once!!!!!, no matter how often I click the button"
end sub
```

Then in the module where I initialize the `listboxes` I create several object of my class(`CListMover`):

```
   ' Input box ....
    With GUI_Excel.ListBox_Header_Input
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .columnWidths = "180;50"
    End With


    For i = 1 To lastColumn
        colTitle = Trim(UCase(wsIn.Cells(headerRow, i).value))
        GUI_Excel.ListBox_ColumnHeaderInputFile.AddItem colTitle
        GUI_Excel.ListBox_ColumnHeaderInputFile.List(i - 1, 1) = i

    Next i

    ' Output box ......
    With GUI_Excel.ListBox_ColumnHeaderOutputFile
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .columnWidths = "180;50;100;100"
    End With


    'Move from input to output...
    Set m_clsListMoveIn = New CListMover
    With m_clsListMoveIn
        Set .TransferButton = GUI_Excel.CommandButton_MoveIn
        Set .transferFromList = GUI_Excel.ListBox_ColumnHeaderInputFile
        Set .TransferToList = GUI_Excel.ListBox_ColumnHeaderOutputFile
        .ReverseListBox = True
    End With

    'Move from output to input, i.e delete...
    Set m_clsListMoveOut = New CListMover
    With m_clsListMoveOut
        Set .TransferButton = GUI_Excel.CommandButton_MoveOut
        Set .transferFromList = GUI_Excel.ListBox_Header_Output

        .RemoveItemOnTransfer = True
        .DeleteItemFromList = True

    End With

    ' Move up down ....
    Set m_clsListMoveUpDown = New CListMover
    With m_clsListMoveUpDown
        Set .MoveDownButton = GUI_Excel.CommandButton_MoveDown
        Set .MoveUpButton = GUI_Excel.CommandButton_MoveUp
        Set .UpDownList = GUI_Excel.ListBox_Header_Output
    End With

    GoTo terminate

terminate:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**The problem:**
The events only seems to trigger once! So I get all my items up in the input box and I can move item over once, after that it stops responding to my command button. Do I need to do something with the events of the button itself?

```
Private Sub CommandButton_MoveIn_Click()

End Sub
```

The funny thing it works fine in excel, but not in word....

Comment: Is this in a User Form? On the document surface?

Comment: yes, it is a userform. It seems like : 
Private m_clsListMoveUpDown As CListMover
Private m_clsListMoveIn As CListMover
Private m_clsListMoveOut As CListMover   Needs to be decleread in the userform module and not in any other module.

Comment: Yes, the events need to be declared in the UserForm module. UserForms are actually *classes* (which is why they can have events). If you want the main part of the code in a "plain" module you can put it there and call it from within the event.